# What would self be in this instance? — Nowhere in the docs does it say what self should be

Tags: python

```
import cfbd  # API for accessing all sorts of college football data.

team_player_stats = cfbd.PlayersApi.get_player_season_stats(self=[], year=2019, team="Georgia", category="passing")
print(team_player_stats)
```

It says `self` is not defined, but I am not sure what `self` is.

Comment: I have tried to add a blank data type, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation for `cfbd.PlayersApi.get_player_season_stats`?  I can't find it.

Comment: Yes, here it is @Bill https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/master/docs/PlayersApi.md#get_player_season_stats

Comment: The argument `self` is a Python feature of classes not an argument to be passed when calling this method. To learn more about what self is and Python classes, I suggest this tutorial: [Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) in Python 3](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with how to use Python classes and methods?

If you follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/master/docs/PlayersApi.md#get_player_season_stats) it shows you how to instantiate a `PlayersApi` and use the method `get_player_season_stats`:

```
# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = cfbd.PlayersApi()
year = 56 # int | Year filter
team = 'team_example' # str | Team filter (optional)
conference = 'conference_example' # str | Conference abbreviation filter (optional)
start_week = 56 # int | Start week filter (optional)
end_week = 56 # int | Start week filter (optional)
season_type = 'season_type_example' # str | Season type filter (regular, postseason, or both) (optional)
category = 'category_example' # str | Stat category filter (e.g. passing) (optional)

try:
    # Player stats by season
    api_response = api_instance.get_player_season_stats(year, team=team, conference=conference, start_week=start_week, end_week=end_week, season_type=season_type, category=category)
    print(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling PlayersApi->get_player_season_stats: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: Yes, I am very new to the programming scene and I don't have that great of an understanding. When I run this exact code, it says there is a 500 server error.

Comment: Okay, not sure why.  I suggest you post another question showing the code you tried and the details of that error message and someone who is more familiar with cfbd can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Self is used for class method declaration as sort of an initial value.
In this case you are trying to declare an empty list on the object self.

Try remove the declaration. self is not used to have some kind of value in it.

Cheers

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Davis/Documents/Pycharm Projects/cffbot/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    team_player_stats = cfbd.PlayersApi.get_player_season_stats(year=2019, team="Georgia", category="passing")
TypeError: get_player_season_stats() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
This is the error that I get when running the code stated in the original post I made. I have tried it without adding a value to self.

Comment: Well this seems strange. Whats the error message if you include self just like this in the method. ```team_player_stats = cfbd.PlayersApi.get_player_season_stats(self, year=2019, team="Georgia", category="passing")```

Comment: Had another answer on reddit, thank you though. The problem was that PlayerApi was a constructor method and I actually had to call it with ().